# PHP: Giving a 404 doesn't work

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I'm using the following code to display a 404 if the requested page couldn't be found:

```
if($page_exists)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);

    $ui->title = '404 Not Found';

    $o .= '<h1>Not found!</h1>' . "\n";
    $o .= '<p>The requested page could not be found.</p>' . "\n";
}

echo $ui->top();
echo $o;
echo $ui->bottom();
```

But for some reason I'm never getting my 404 status code - it gives a 200 instead. I've checked and double-checked that there's no actual output before the header(), and when I check the PHP error codes there's nothing else than some notices. I've also tested a location header instead, which doesn't work neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with `HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: FastCGI? Try Status: 404 Not Found

Comment: Which webserver are you using? Which SAPI are you using? Do you have an example URI online?

Comment: Replace the hard coded `HTTP/1.0` with `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` and see it that helps. HTTP/1.0 was used in dinosaur age.

Comment: I'm using an Apache server. I tried HTTP/1.1 without success, and actually it shouldn't make much difference as long as I use the $http_response_code parameter in header().

Comment: I've also tried "Status: Not Found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved - for some reason a file was saved with BOM.

Answer (score 1):

As Jared says, for FastCGI you must use the other form

`header("Status: 404 Not Found");`

I would start there.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php